# How to copy xlCellTypeVisible cells and keep their formatting (bold text)?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I am using this piece of code to copy and paste some stuff:

```
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

            Wsh.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            Wsh.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
            Wsh.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

However, when it pastes it loses the formatting. Some of the text I am copying is bold and I would like it to remain bold. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Straight copy destination:=Wsh.Cells(1) retains font color and bold for me. Are these formulas that you have to pastespecial, values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a straight Copy direct to destination then come back and pick up the column widths that were left behind.

```
with .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .copy destination:=Wsh.Cells(1)
    .copy
    Wsh.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
end with
```